# How to use CUPTI to get metrics related to Launch Metrics, Source Metrics and Instructions Per Opcode Metrics

Tags: cuda, profiling, nvidia, nsight

I am able to use ncu to get the metrics related to Launch Metrics, Source Metrics and Instructions Per Opcode Metrics (found [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/ProfilingGuide/#metrics-reference)). However I am unable to use CUPTI to get the values after modifying the `METRIC_NAME` in the sample code `/usr/local/cuda-11.8/extras/CUPTI/samples/callback_profiling/callback_profiling.cu`. I get an error

`FAILED: NVPW_MetricsEvaluator_ConvertMetricNameToMetricEvalRequest(&convertMetricToEvalRequest) with error NVPA_STATUS_INVALID_ARGUMENT`.

How can I, for example, get the values like `memory_l2_theoretical_sectors_global` or `sass__inst_executed_per_opcode` as shown in the linked manual? (I am able to get these values using Nsight Compute, hence these values can be obtained on my system.)
I know the available metrics can be queried using `--query-metrics`, but those metrics are not the same as the link I have mentioned above.

Can someone let me know how do I get the values using CUPTI? Is there any Nvidia CUPTI sample for the same?

A small kernel to profile:

```
#define N (2048 * 8)
#define THREADS_PER_BLOCK 512

void __device__ add1_device(const int x, const int y, int *z)
{
    
    *z = x * y;
    
}

__global__ void dot(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    __shared__ int temp[THREADS_PER_BLOCK];
    int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    // temp[threadIdx.x] = a[index] * b[index];
    add1_device(a[index], b[index], &temp[threadIdx.x]);    // Comment this line and uncomment the previous to not use the _-device__ 

    __syncthreads();

    if (threadIdx.x == 0)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < THREADS_PER_BLOCK; i++)
        {
            sum += temp[i];
        }
        atomicAdd(c, sum);
    }
}


    int *a, *b, *c;
    int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;
    int size = N * sizeof(int);

    //allocate space for the variables on the device
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_a, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_b, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_c, sizeof(int));

    //allocate space for the variables on the host
    a = (int *)malloc(size);
    b = (int *)malloc(size);
    c = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

    //this is our ground truth
    int prodTest = 0;
    //generate numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % 10;
        b[i] = rand() % 10;
    }

    *c = 0;

    cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_c, c, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dot<<< N / THREADS_PER_BLOCK, THREADS_PER_BLOCK >>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);
    cudaFree(dev_c);
```

Comment: This is pretty much a copy of a question that was previously closed and then probably deleted by OP. I "agree" that it is unlucky that ncu metrics and CUPTI metrics are very similar in name but not necessarily the same. I don't think that there is some general way of translating from one API to the other. Rather I would expect the solution to be specific to each metric or groups of them.

Comment: @talonmies yes I have checked the CUPTI documentation and I can't find the metrics I have asked, however ncu provides those metrics, hence my question if there is any way to retrieve those data using CUPTI

Answer (score 1):

The following groups of metrics are calculated by Nsight Compute and are not available in CUPTI as metrics:

https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/ProfilingGuide/#metrics-reference

- Launch Metrics
- Device Attributes
- Source Metrics
- Instructions Per Opcode Metrics